# How do I join a table and change the names of the returned columns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got a MS SQL 2008 table called "fruits" that looks like this:

```
id   name           category_id
--   ------------   -----------
 1   Apples                   4
 2   Bananas                  6
 3   Crackers                 6
```

and another table called "categories" with:

```
id   category_name
--   -------------
 4   Foo
 6   Bar
```

How do I produce a query that will return results that look like:

```
fruit_name  fruit_category_name
----------  -------------------
Apples      Foo
Bananas     Bar
Crackers    Bar
```

(The columns must be exactly that name because I'm trying to write a CSV.)

Comment: Use the `AS` (alias) keyword.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT f.name AS fruit_name, c.category_name AS fruit_category_name
FROM fruits AS f
INNER JOIN categories AS c ON c.id = f.category_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT f.name AS fruit_name, c.category_name AS fruit_category_name
FROM fruits f INNER JOIN categories c
ON f.id = c.id
ORDER BY f.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select name as fruit_name, category_name as fruit_category_name
from fruits
inner join categories on (fruits.category_id = categories.id)
order by fruit_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fruits.name AS fruit_name, categories.category_name AS fruit_category_name FROM fruits INNER JOIN categories ON (fruits.category_id = categories.category_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```
SELECT
    f.name AS fruit_name,
    c.category_name AS fruit_category_name
FROM
    fruits f
JOIN
    categories c ON c.id = f.category_id
ORDER BY
    fruit_name DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

you can rename a column in one of two ways:

```
SELECT
    ColumnName AS DisplayName
    FROM ...
```

or

```
SELECT
    DisplayName = ColumnName
    FROM ...
```

Remember, use `[` and `]` if you need to use special characters (like space) within the display name:

```
SELECT
    ColumnName AS [Display Name]
    FROM ...
```

or

```
SELECT
    [Display Name] = ColumnName
    FROM ...
```

You can do your join like this:

```
SELECT 
    f.name AS fruit_name
        ,c.category_name AS fruit_category_name
    FROM Fruits             f
    INNER JOIN Categories   c ON c.id=f.category_id
```